Unable to extract complete page source using selenium
I am using VBA Selenium for data extraction. My code is extracting the page source but is ignoring data within script tags. How to resolve this issue?
My current code:
Dim d As WebDriver
Set d = New ChromeDriver
d.Start "Chrome"
d.get "https://www.bloomingdales.com/shop/product/french-connection-ennis-satin-bell-sleeve-mini-dress?ID=5250376&CategoryID=21683"
inputString = d.PageSource

Above code is extracting everything in source but ignoring following data
 <script>window.__INITIAL_STATE__={"envProps":
"traits":{"colors":{"selectedColor":2877902},"sizes":{"selectedSize":0}}

basically what i want is to extract all selectedsize values.

You'd need to execute javascript to get those stored values.  You could return window, and parse from there...

Above suggestion from Mr.browsermator resolve my issue.Now i am using following code and data is visible properly.
initialstate = d.ExecuteScript("return JSON.stringify(window.__INITIAL_STATE__);")

